# qt qml display image from web server to my qt quick app

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

hi i have image stored in google drive or mega a want to display it using my qt android app
i thinks the problem is this
`QML Image: Erreur de décodage`
`Format d'image non support`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/**102A4WrjwOlySb8LWfMZ7CiIrt0f-12CO/view?usp=sharing**
`this work well to my app`
https://zupimages.net/up/21/05/cwkf.png

Comment: When I click that link I get a 404, are you sure that is the correct link? Or maybe the file is not publicly visible?

Comment: its not visible

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/102A4WrjwOlySb8LWfMZ7CiIrt0f-12CO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: its know visible but dont work in my app

Comment: https://zupimages.net/up/21/05/cwkf.png

Comment: but the lien zupimage work very well in my app

Comment: Could you reprdoce a  part of your code here? the part where you try to access this image on google drive or zupimages. Also add "android" tag to your question to make it visible in the android related entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your Google Drive URL a bit as advised [here](https://medium.com/apps-ru-en/create-direct-links-to-your-files-on-google-drive-fb5b0cd4dfb6) to get a direct link to the image file.

Modified URL format:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

Example QML image which displays your Google Drive image:

```
Image {
    source: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=102A4WrjwOlySb8LWfMZ7CiIrt0f-12CO"
}
```

Comment: thanks i try to modify my google drive url and coming late

Comment: thanks working nice ..... can i do that whit audio file too?